# How to return specific rows first and then randomize the rest in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have this table where I have about 250 rows. What I want is to return all the rows, but first I want to display the six rows where the field `spazio = 'auditorium'` and then display all the remaining rows in a random order.
I've tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY case when spazio = 'auditorium' then case spazio != 'auditorium' RAND()
```

But it's not returning what I want.

Comment: `but it's not at all returning what I want` ← So what *is* it returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an `ELSE`, a `THEN`, and an `END`. You also need to assign a number to your first `THEN`, which I'm going to say should be 0 so it's the first in an `ASC` order.

`ORDER BY` is reducing everything to a number value to put them in order. The `CASE` statement needs to give it a number back. Not to mention that `RAND` returns a number between 0 and 1, so a decimal. In fact, it could return 0 also, so it's safer to add 1.

`` SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY CASE WHEN `spazio` = "auditorium" THEN 0 ELSE RAND() + 1 END ASC ``

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend two `order by` keys:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
ORDER BY (spazio = 'auditorium') desc, RAND()
```

The first condition is a boolean.  Because `true` > `false`, you want a descending sort to get the auditoria first in the result set.